# Sum only those that are visible

Tags: excel, vba

Recently, I have been trying to code a VBA to assist me in summing a column and divide by counter to get average. However, I have a new requirement that is it is only going to sum up those that are visible. Any idea on how should I proceed? Below is my code,

```
Sub test3()
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim total As Double
    counter = 3
    total = 0
    Dim i As Double
    FinalRow = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
        For Row = 3 To FinalRow
            If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, "C")) And Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(Row + 1, "C")) Then
                If ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, "B").Value = True Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, "M").Value = 100
                    For i = counter To Row
                    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "F")) Then
                            With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "F")
                                .Value = Now
                                .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
                                If (.Value - .Offset(0, 2).Value) >= 0 Then
                            .Font.color = vbRed
                        Else
                            .Font.color = vbBlack
                        End If
                         End With
                         End If
                         Next i
                         End If
                    If (ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, "L").Value = 100) Then
                          For i = counter To Row
                    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "F")) Then
                                With ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "F")
                                .Value = Now
                                .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
                                If (.Value - .Offset(0, 2).Value) >= 0 Then
                            .Font.color = vbRed
                        Else
                            .Font.color = vbBlack
                        End If
                         End With
                    End If
                    Next i
                End If
                If Not (ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, "B").Value) = True Then
                    ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, "M").Value = (Application.Sum(Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, "L"), ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, "L")))) / (Row + 1 - counter)

                End If
                counter = Row + 1
             End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This might give you an idea [How to Use a VBA Macro to Sum Only Visible Cells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150363)

Comment: Haha.... Thanks Peter. But nowI am in complete lost on how to apply in my case. A little confusing. Hope someone can give me a tips on two.

Comment: You want `Subtotal` rather than `Sum`

Comment: Tried. Returns error. Been trying all different methods but it seems fruitless. Thanks Rory.

Comment: I have tried this code " ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, "M").Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(counter, "L"), ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, "L")))) / (Row + 1 - counter)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This testcode works for me, just change it as you need it:

```
Sub TestSumme()
Dim Summe As Long
Summe = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
MsgBox (Summe)
End Sub
```